# Inherited Class using as datacontract

Tags: wcf

Actually I Have a Problem Using a Inherited Class as a DataContract. Below is My Code

```
[DataContract]
public class PartialTestClass
{
}

[DataContract]
public class TestClass : PartialTestClass
{
}

[ServiceContract(Name = "IMessageContract", 
CallbackContract = typeof(IMessageCallback))]
public interface IMessageContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    PartialTestClass Test(PartialTestClass partialTestClass);
}
```

Client Side:

```
PartialTestClass p = new TestClass();
p.Name = "Afshin.Ahmari";
TestClass p2 = (TestClass)Proxy.Test(p);
```

Can Anybody help me with this

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Child classes need to be [known types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx) of the base class:

```
    [DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(TestClass))]
    public class PartialTestClass { }
```